# migration RC4 -> RC5 troubleshooting

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular, angular-meteor

Have problem with migration after updating al npm modules

**main.ts:**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from './app.routes';

import { PartiesFormComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-form.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
// PartiesListComponent,
// PartyDetailsComponent,
PartiesFormComponent
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
/* Router*/
RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS),
],
providers: [
APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { PartiesListComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-list.component';

import template from './app.component.html';

@Component({
selector: 'app',
template,
directives: [
PartiesListComponent,
]
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.routes.ts:**

> import { RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
>
> ```
> import { PartiesListComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-list.component';
> import { PartiesFormComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-form.component';
>
> const routes: RouterConfig = [
> { path: '', component: PartiesListComponent},
> // { path: 'party/:partyId', component: PartyDetailsComponent },
> // { path: 'edit/:partyId', component: PartyEditComponent },
> { path: 'new', component: PartiesFormComponent},
> ];
>
> export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
> provideRouter(routes)
> ];
> ```

**HAVE:**

> Invalid route configuration: Array cannot be specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Resolved by
changes in **app.routes.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
....some code.....
const appRoutes: Routes = [
....some code.....
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

BUT now have:

```
browser_adapter.js: 93EXCEPTION: 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'completer' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `app.routes.ts` as below :

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PartiesListComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-list.component';
import { PartiesFormComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-form.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PartiesListComponent},
  { path: 'new', component: PartiesFormComponent},
];
```

Change your `app.module.ts` as below :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';

import { PartiesFormComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-form.component';
import { PartiesListComponent } from './imports/parties/parties-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PartiesFormComponent,
    PartiesListComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: true}),
  ]    
})
export class AppModule { }
```